No consigo aplicar @Valid en un creación simple de encuesta
En mi controller he definido el siguiente endpoint:
@PostMapping("/encuestas")
public ResponseEntity<?>createEncuesta(**@Valid** @RequestBody Encuesta encuesta){
    encuesta = encuestaRepository.save(encuesta);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    URI newEncuestaUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
            .fromCurrentRequest()
            .path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(encuesta.getId()).toUri();
    httpHeaders.setLocation(newEncuestaUri);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
} 

En el model, en la entidad encuesta he declarado el siguiente campo
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "pregunta")
private String pregunta;

Como veis he añadido @Valid para validar que cuando introduzcamos una nueva encuesta si no tiene el parámetro pregunta, nos salte un error y no nos deje crearla. Y ahí viene el problema, me deja crearla sin problema, no me notifica ningún error, me da un 201 OK.
He revisado las dependencias etc pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar.
Muchas gracias por vuesta atención, un saludo a todos.

Tienes como dependencia de tu proyecto spring-boot-starter-validation?

Si lo tengo añadido : 
org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-validation


¿Tienes los getters y setters en la entidad encuesta? ¿Qué response body estás enviando que te deja crearla? ¿pregunta es un campo de encuesta o de un objeto hijo de encuesta? Por favor agrega más detalles a tu pregunta.
PD: no está de más hacer un mvn clean y probar todo de nuevo.

Buenas Jaime, especifico algo mas es un curso de springBoot de udemy, yo voy siguiendo los paso soy recien graduado, los getters y setter nos los tiene implementados, mando un json: {
"pregunta": "¿Cuál es tu lenguaje de programación favorito?",
"opciones": [
{"texto": "Java"},
{"texto": "HTML"},
{"texto": "CSS"},
{"texto": "JavaScript"}
]
}
La teoria es que si elimino el parametro pregunta deberia darme error ya que indique NotEmpty en la columna pregunta, y añadi @Valid. Encuesta es el objeto y pregunta su atributo.
